# How to disconnect from VSTS from VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

Our project is within Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), and we use VS2013 to connect to VSTS.

When we click on **Connect to Team Project** option from VS2013 IDE, no credentials dialog appears, and VS2013 automatically connects my project to the online Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

When I click on **Disconnect** option from the IDE **Team Menu**, and try again my project is still connects to VSTS. I tried deleting all the cookies and passwords from Internet Explorer but still issue is not resolved.

I checked Windows Credentials too, but I did not find any there. Here is a screen shot image.

[image: Screen shot showing no credentials.]

Can you help me to find out where I need to remove **VSTS credentials** from my computer. Every time that I open that project and click on **Connect to Team Project**, I want VS2013 to ask for credentials to connect to VSTS.

Please help me find the correct method to accomplish this goal. Thank you.

Comment: You say "online TFS".  Are you using TFS, the on-premises product?  Or are you using Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: i am not using  on-premises TFS rather using online TFS (visual Studio Team Services)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  VSTS is not generally known as "online TFS".  The two product names refer to two different, mutually exclusive products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the system will remember the credential once you conneted to the VSTS.

So, we cannot achieve that as you said "`every time i open that project and when i click on connect to team project then VS2013 ask for credentials to connect to VSTS.`" unless you **clean/reset the user data every time** or run Visual Studio with another user ever time.

You can try below items to clean the credentials to popup the enter credential dialog:

- Remove all related credentials from Credential Manager as you did.
- Clear the IE(or any other browser) stored passwords, reference below screenshot.
- Delete the key from registry:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp`
- Delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\{Ver}\Cache\Volatile\{SomeGUID}_https\VersionContr‌​ol.config`
- Delete the credential stored json file under :
  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService`
- Run Visual Studio with another user:  (See [Runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) for details)

  `Runas /profile /user:[DOMAIN]\[user] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`
- Reset user data by running this command : `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`

[image]